# Is it possible to create a new PDB from java?

Tags: java, oracle12c

For one of my poc, I would like to create a new PDB from java.

I am able to get cdb connection say,

```
Connection cdbConnection = DBUtils.getDBConnection(Constants.DB_CDB_NAME, Constants.DB_CDB_USER_NAME, Constants.DB_CDB_PASSWORD);
```

Now am trying to clone PDB3: `CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE PDB5 FROM PDB3;`

```
public static void createPluggableDB(Connection cdbConnection) {
  try (Statement stmt = cdbConnection.createStatement();) {
     stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE PDB5 FROM PDB3;");
  } catch (SQLException exception) {
    // exception handling
  }
}
```

When I execute this, am getting,

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1052)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:537)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:255)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:610)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:213)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:37)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:887)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1136)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1754)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1709)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:300)
at com.xit.gtw.db.DBUtils.executeDBScripts(DBUtils.java:43)
at PluggableDBBuilder.createPluggableDB(PluggableDBBuilder.java:51)
at PluggableDBBuilder.main(PluggableDBBuilder.java:35)
```

Is it possible to create a PDB from java?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you need to provide a correct statement. "*ORA-00922: missing or invalid option*" tells you that your syntax is missing something.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thanks for the reply.  The same statement 'CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE PDB5 FROM PDB3;' is executing successfully thro sqlplus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have the semicolon in the string you pass to `executeUpdate()`; it's a statement separator not part of the statement. So remove that:

```
stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE PDB5 FROM PDB3");
```

That applies to any statement you try to execute through JDBC (or, indeed, through many other mechanisms - including `execute immediate`).